# Intent object not triggering intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how `Intent`s and `intent-filter`s work, but it seems to me that this should be a straight-forward case. However, it's not working.

Here is the Intent I'm sending:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.connectsy.event");
startActivity(i);
```

And here is the intent-filter:

```
<activity android:name=".events.EventView">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.connectsy.event" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And finally, the error I'm recieving:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.connectsy.event }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's the answer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires):

> Android treats all implicit intents
>   passed to startActivity()  as if they
>   contained at least one category:
>   "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (the
>   CATEGORY_DEFAULT constant). Therefore,
>   activities that are willing to receive
>   implicit intents must include
>   "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" in
>   their intent filters.

Add

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to your intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml